# How to show all users filtering with an atrribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show only the emails of my users, this is my controller

```rb
def all
  @users = User.all
end
```

I am trying to do that using jbuilder, but when I do the request, it does not give nothing

just i see nothing, the problem what i have is finding the correct view for jbuilder

this is my route:

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1, defaults: { format: :json} do
      get '/all', to: 'users#all'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What it means? Like this: `[{ "email": "email1", "name": "Name1" }, { "email": "email2", "name": "Name2" }]`?

Comment: might i suggest that you edit your post a little. your error is that you arent finding the correct view and your code is still missing a closing end (in the first code block). +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to assign instance varible in the controller action to pass it to jbuider view

```rb
def all
  @users = User.all
end
```

Than build JSON in `app/views/api/v1/user/all.json.jbuilder`. BTW controller names are usually plural, `users` is better than `user`

```rb
json.array! @users, :email, :name
```

It will generate JSON like this

```json
[{ "email": "email1", "name": "Name1" }, { "email": "email2", "name": "Name2" }]
```

Comment: @mechnicov did you tried with rails 7, it seems like a new fail

Answer (score 1):

The code you are showing looks like its missing an `end` for your `do` block - thats not the error though.

Without further digging I think you might not have a corresponding view file, something like **views/users/index.json.jbuilder**.
inside there you might want to stick your jbuilder stuff (going with the rails convention):

```rb
# users_controller.rb
def index
  @users = User.all
end


# views/users/index.json.jbuilder
json.array! @users do |user|
  json.extract! user, :email, :name
end
```

you are using an `all` action in your controller however and if your route for that is fine you can swap **index** for **all**

```rb
# users_controller.rb
def all
  @users = User.all
end


# views/users/all.json.jbuilder
json.array! @users do |user|
  json.extract! user, :email, :name
end
```

its always good to take a look at the docs when you bump up against this kinda stuff:
[jbuilder gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

Comment: i edited my jbuilder stuff a little, but **_not showing me nothing_** doesnt help me narrow down where else you might have an issue.

Comment: why do you are naming show.json... why show...?

Comment: That should be `all` as in OP question

Comment: You still use `show.json.jbuilder` :) And also use wrong relative path: `views`, not `app/views`

Comment: yeah in the text, fixed that, but the code itself was/is correct. as for the path: thats a tiny bit overkill as i was just making sure OP understood which folder this was supposed to be in. originally there was no view at all. cheers

Comment: @Haumer do you have any suggestions more to solve this problem?

Comment: @mtsyumm can you confirm that you have a view file, a valid route and an unchanged error?

Comment: Rails expects a view. your views dont need to return html and in your case, using an api, they might return json, indicated by the **.json.jbuilder** extension. your error suggests your app isnt finding the correct view. up to you